# How can I use the map/walk functions of purrr to write each layer within a SpatRaster object (terra package)

Tags: r, raster, purrr, spatial, terra

I have a SpatRaster object preds_cut (class SpatRaster of terra package) composed of different layers
I want to write each layer stored in preds_cut using the writeRaster function

The following code works beautifully

```
for (p in 1:nlyr(preds_cut)) {
  writeRaster(preds_cut[[p]], filename = paste0("../data/predictors/preds_cut", "/", names(preds_cut)[p], ".tif"))
}
```

I'd like to subsitute it with the walk function ..however it seems that the purrr package is not suitable for SpatRaster object ..or at least I wasn't able to write a function to achieve this ... I tried the following options:

```
 purrr::walk(preds_cut,~writeRaster,filename=glue::glue("../data/predictors/preds_cut/{x}.tif"))
Error in `set_names()`:
! The size of `nm` (18) must be compatible with the size of `x` (1).

purrr::walk(preds_cut, function(x){
 path <- file.path("../data/predictors/preds_cut", glue::glue('{x}.tif'))
 writeRaste(x, path)
})
```

Can anyone help me sort this out?
Thanks

Comment: You are using `x` as a SpatRaster and also as a filename. Whichever it is, it cannot be the other at the same time

Comment: @RobertHijmans .. I am using x to indicate each layer of the SpatRaster as the objective is to save each individual layer within the SpatRaster .. the walk function is used to apply a function ..in this case writeraster.. to each element of the list (each element =each layer=x)

Comment: You also use it as a filename in `glue('{x}.tif'))`

Comment: @RobertHijmans yes because I want to assign to each layer their right name .. how would you do that using walk?

Answer (score 2):

This would be a better approach

```
ff <- file.path("../data/predictors/preds_cut", 
                     paste0(names(preds_cut), ".tif"))
 
writeRaster(preds_cut, filename=ff)
```